# ScalaPlay / Angular2 - SBT compiling dependencies typescript files

Tags: scala, playframework, angular, compilation, sbt

My team and I are currently working on a project where we have injected the [joost-de-vries plugins](https://github.com/joost-de-vries) to compile our typescript files.
Everything was working fine until we had to use the angular2-jwt dependency which contains ts files. The problem is that those files are getting compiled even though they are not included in rootDir and included in the excluded folders.

When compiling we get the following mistake :

```
TS6059 File 'path/to/file' is not under 'rootDir' 'rootDir/path'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

As a consequence, the ts files are compiled as empty folders (with a js extension though). The rootDir compiler option is definitely the key to it but we can't seem to find any solution after a long week of research and tries. Is there already a workaround the fact that rootDir is an ignored compiler option? If not is it a work in progress or can we do anything about it?

About our project, we are using the Play 2.5.4, Scala 2.11.8 and are using the latest versions available on webjars for angular2 RC4 (basically the webjars used in [play-angular2-typescript](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript) from joost-de-vries).

Thanks in advance for your answers.